# Join a column into a string

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xpath

I *think* I need to better understand the FOR XML PATH to get this working. Maybe you can help me with this simple example:

Given

```
DECLARE @p VARCHAR(200)
DECLARE @phn TABLE (Phone VARCHAR(25))
INSERT INTO @phn VALUES('204-721-1532')
INSERT INTO @phn VALUES('306-922-2058')
INSERT INTO @phn VALUES('204-728-3852')
```

I want to change all the rows in @phn.Phone into a VARCHAR, which, if it were only Python, would be something like

```
SET @p = ', '.join(@phn.Phone) # Alas
```

Now, **THIS** works up to a point:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Phone+', ' FROM @phn FOR XML PATH('')
==> 204-721-1532, 204-728-3852, 306-922-2058,
```

There's that trailing comma, but no problem there. What I need is to get this result into a VARCHAR variable, something like

```
SELECT DISTINCT @p = Phone+', ' FROM @phn FOR XML PATH('')
```

But that's not allowed (Msg 6819, Level 16, State 3, Line 45/The FOR XML clause is not allowed in a ASSIGNMENT statement.)

Eventually, this is going to go into a scalar function, and I want the function to RETURN the joined up string.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need XML Path, just a select will do

```
DECLARE @p VARCHAR(200)
DECLARE @phn TABLE (Phone VARCHAR(25))
INSERT INTO @phn VALUES('204-721-1532')
INSERT INTO @phn VALUES('306-922-2058')
INSERT INTO @phn VALUES('204-728-3852')


SET @p = ''
SELECT @p = @p + phone + ', '  from @phn

SELECT @P
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/3444)

How you want to deal with nulls is up to you. You could

- add `COALESCE(Phone,'')`
- use a case statement `CASE WHEN phone is not null THEN phone + ', ' ELSE '' END`
- use a where `WHERE phone is not null`
- or even `CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL = OFF` but that's supposed to be deprecated

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need:

[Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/12165)

```
DECLARE @p VARCHAR(200)
DECLARE @phn TABLE (Phone VARCHAR(25))
INSERT INTO @phn VALUES('204-721-1532')
INSERT INTO @phn VALUES('306-922-2058')
INSERT INTO @phn VALUES('204-728-3852')

--Using Isnull() function to eliminate tralling comma
select @p = isnull(@p + ', ','') + Phone
from @phn

select @p

Results: 
204-721-1532, 306-922-2058, 204-728-3852
```